# Android intent sms help

Tags: android, sms, android-intent

Hi Im making the finishing touches on my first app have hit a roadblock Im trying to call the results of my

```
textview1.getText(k);
```

down below to the `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item,View v)`  where an intent allows the user to send it as an text message but for some odd reason its not reading (k) my guess is it can't find the variable(k) for some odd reason. full code is down below any help is welcomed.

P.S  Sorry my code is sloppy still a little new to programming.

```
package com.Converter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Converter extends Activity {

    Button b1 ;
    EditText edittext;
    RadioButton rad1, rad2;
    TextView textview1 ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        rad1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad1);
        rad2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad2); 
       textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
           }
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(rad1.isChecked())
           {
               String s1 = edittext.getText().toString();
               byte[] bytes = s1.getBytes();
               StringBuilder k= new StringBuilder();
               for (byte b : bytes)
                  {
                     int val = b - '0';
                     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                     {
                        k.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                        val <<= 1;
                     }
                    k.append(' ');
                  }

                textview1.setText(k);
           }

        if(rad2.isChecked())
        {
            int charCode;
            String k = "";
            String b = edittext.getText().toString();;
            while (b.length() > 8) {
                charCode = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(0, 8),2);
                k += new Character((char)charCode).toString();
                b = b.substring(8);
            }
            if (b.length() > 0) {
                //attempt handle any trailing bits that might be left
                charCode = Integer.parseInt(b,2);
                k += new Character((char)charCode).toString();
            }

            textview1.setText(k);
        }
        }
     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item,View v) {
         String smsbody = textview1.getText(k);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.icon:  Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsbody); 
            sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
                                break;
            case R.id.text:     Toast.makeText(this, "Testing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
            case R.id.icontext: Toast.makeText(this, "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
        }
        return true;
    }



    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Which section of this code isn't working?  What is the expected behavior, and what is happening now?

Comment: Sorry the section of the code not working is the method  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item,View v) its not calling K from the Onclick method

Answer (score 1):

If you are refering to

```
String smsbody = textview1.setText(k);
```

it needs to be changed to

```
String smsbody = textview1.getText(k);
```

as you are reading the text, not setting it.

**Edit**

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
           btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do your logic here

            }
        });
```

Here's a basic onClick interface model

Comment: You need your button to implement an onClickListener...your current onClick is just a private method you created and isn't really doing anything...reference the edit. Edit: I'm assuming you are using the button to set the text or if b1 is just an extraneous variable correct me

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `String smsbody = textview1.getText();` Note the **g**et, not **s**et.

Comment: Yes i was meaning to change that it slipped my mind thank you now i just need to figure out why the results of my aren't being called down to the menu.